# CSVファイルの出力時、pandasがファイルパスを読み込めない

Tags: python

読み込みたいcsvファイルはpyとともにCドライブの下に保存されています。

```
#import sys
#print(sys.version)

#テストプログラム
import os
# カレントフォルダを変更
os.chdir(r"C:/Python/csv_diff")

#ディレクトリ内のファイルを表示
print(os.listdir())

#import time

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# CSVファイルの読み込み

#col_names = ['c{0:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(100)]

df_1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
#df_2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')

#df_1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', encoding=&quot;shift-jis&quot;, names = col_names)

# CSVファイルの出力

print(df_1)
#print(df_2)
#print(df_1 == df_2)

#print(csv_input.size)
```

Comment: 読み込みたいのに見つからないのか, CSVファイル出力したいのか, どちらでしょうか？ それとも両方？

Comment: 今の書き方はCSVファイルがカレントの作業ディレクトリにある前提になっています。プログラムソースファイルの場所とカレントの作業ディレクトリの場所の間に直接的な連携はありません。プログラム起動時の手作業での準備やツール/IDEの設定を行うか、プログラムソース上でプログラムソースファイルと同じディレクトリをカレントの作業ディレクトリに変更するか、ファイルを指定する際にドライブ名から始まるフルパス名を指定する必要があります。ちなみにそれらのファイルのディレクトリが何処に有るかといった事も追記してください。

Comment: CSVの差分を比較し、差分があるところのみを出力するプログラムを作っろうとしています。

Comment: コードやエラーは省略せずにそのまま質問に含めてください。「ファイルパスを読み込めない」も恐らくはもっとメッセージが表示されている気がします。

Comment: 「読み込めない」というのは質問のコードの話ですか？それとも, コメントに追記されたコードは動くコードですか？
もし未だに読み込めないのであれば, 回答に示したカレント以下を探すスクリプト, あるいは `C:/Python/csv_diff/` 以下を探すスクリプトではどうなりましたか？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！(？ 今更かもだけど)
現在のマイナス票は [こらちの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/91772/)と状況が似てる気もします。ただ状況がわかりません。未だ見つかっていないのか, 見つかったのが `C:/Python/csv_diff/` なのか。その辺りを [編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/91691/edit) にて質問文に記述すると他の人にも伝わるかもだし, そうしていくと票も変わっていくでしょう。
また「CSVの差分を比較し、差分があるところのみを出力」と「ファイルが(未だに)見つからない」では同じ質問にするにはムリがあるように思います。未だ見つかっていないのなら 新たに別の質問にすると良いでしょう

Answer (score 0):

質問された方がコメント欄に書かれていた「CSVを比較し，差があるところのみを出力する」に興味を持ち，自分なりに作ってみました。
テスト用CSV作成コード，比較コード，比較出力を順に示します。なお，このまま試す場合はカレントに 'csv' ディレクトリを用意ください。

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv_dir = './csv/'  # a trailing '/' required
csv1 = csv_dir + 'test1.csv'
csv2 = csv_dir + 'test2.csv'

if not os.path.isdir(csv_dir):
    print(f'error: {csv_dir} does not exist.')
    sys.exit(1)

n, m = 5, 12
nm = n * m
ary1 = np.arange(1, nm + 1)
np.random.seed(7)
ary2 = ary1 + (np.random.rand(nm) + 0.1).astype(int)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ary1.reshape(n, m))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(ary2.reshape(n, m))

df1.to_csv(csv1, header=False, index=False)
df2.to_csv(csv2, header=False, index=False)
```

```
import os, sys
import string
import pandas as pd

csv_dir = './csv/'  # a trailing '/' required
csv1 = csv_dir + 'test1.csv'
csv2 = csv_dir + 'test2.csv'

# Check existence of CSV files, and read.
if not (os.path.isfile(csv1) and os.path.isfile(csv2)):
    print(f'error: {csv1} or {csv2} do not exist.')
    sys.exit(1)

df1 = pd.read_csv(csv1, header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv(csv2, header=None)

# Check shape identity, and set columns and index(Excel-like).
if not df1.shape == df2.shape:
    print(f'error: {csv1} and {csv2} differ in shape.')
    sys.exit(1)

A_Z = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
xls_col = A_Z + [A_Z[i // 26] + A_Z[i % 26] for i in range(26 * 26)]
df1.columns = xls_col[:df1.columns.size]  # size <= 702 required
df1.index = [str(i) for i in range(1, df1.index.size + 1)]
df2.columns, df2.index = df1.columns, df1.index

# Output DataFrames and cells with different values.
print(f'df1({csv1}):\n{df1}')
print(f'df2({csv2}):\n{df2}')

print('-' * 10)
df_eq = df1.eq(df2)
for c, s in df_eq.items():
    for r, v in s.items():
        if v: continue
        print(f'{c + r}:  {df1.loc[r, c]}  {df2.loc[r, c]}')
```

```
df1(./csv/test1.csv):
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
3  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
4  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
5  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
df2(./csv/test2.csv):
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L
1   1   2   3   4   6   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2  13  14  15  17  17  18  20  20  21  23  23  24
3  26  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
4  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  49
5  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
----------
A3:  25  26
D2:  16  17
E1:  5  6
G2:  19  20
J2:  22  23
L4:  48  49
```

Answer (score -1):

質問が, CSVファイル読み込みたいのに見つからない … のだとして, その回答です。

以下はカレントディレクトリから探す手順
Home ディレクリからなら `csvf = Path.home()/ 'test1.csv'` で
ディレクリのパスが分かっているのなら `Path('./〜')` の `'.'`を書き換えて試してみるとよいでしょう

```py
from pathlib import Path

# この例はカレントディレクトリから探す方法
csvf = Path('./test1.csv')
if not csvf.exists():
    print(f'search: {csvf.parent}')
    for csvf in csvf.parent.glob('**/test*.csv'):
        print(f'hit: {csvf}')
        break

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csvf)
display(df)
```

---

##### 追記

(改訂)
回答のコメントに投稿されたスクリプト(すでに移行済み)が, 質問時のものか, (何か)試してる最中なのか, (回答を元に？)結論がでた・ディレクトリが見つかったのか … がこちらからは判断できません。

なので, `C:/Python/csv_diff` 以下に存在するかも知れない場合の対処。
上記スクリプトの書き換える部分を以下のようにすると確認可能
(`Path` は `WindowsPath` 返すはずだが 環境無いので動作未確認)

```py
csvf = Path('C:/Python/csv_diff/test1.csv')
```