# ２つのtxtファイルに保存されているデータから列が一致するデータを結合して出力したい

Tags: python

以下のような中身の異なる二つのtxtファイルがあります。この二つのデータから、文字列(aaa00など)が一致しているデータだけを抽出し、二つのデータを結合した出力が欲しいです。

このようなコードを教えて頂けたら嬉しいです。よろしくお願いします。

**対象の txt ファイル:**

test1.txt

```
aaa00,123.22,42.11
aba00,163.22,73.11
acc01,298.11,63.28
...
```

test2.txt

```
bbb00,1872
aaa00,2001
aba00,789
caa01,983
...
```

**期待する出力結果:**

```
aaa00,123.22,42.11,2001
aba00,163.22,73.11,789
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　現在いくつかマイナス票が投じられていますが、これはもしかしたらこれまでにご自身で試されたことが質問文に書かれていないからかもしれません。もし既に試してみてうまくいかなかったことがあれば、質問文を [edit] して追記してみてください。どこの部分で困っているのかがより明確になり、質問者さんに合った回答をしやすくなります。　／　ただし個人的には、入力と期待する出力の組が既に書かれていて何をすればよいかは明確ですし、プラス票を入れない人がいるのは分かりますがマイナス票をするほどかなとは思います。どのような点が改善できそうなのかコメントが無いのも不思議でした。まだ投稿直後なので、そのうちプラス票も集まってトントンくらいになるのではないかなとは思います。なので、あまりお気になさらないでください。

Comment: 優しいお言葉ありがとうございます！

Comment: そういえば確認していませんでしたが、この 2 つのデータは同じテキストファイルの中の同じ行に混在して存在するのでしょうか？　それとも 2 つのテキストファイルに別々に保存されていますか？

Comment: 上記の例で説明すると、左がtest1.txt、右がtest2.txtといった別々のファイルになります。

Comment: その二つのファイルを読み込み、aaa00などの文字列が同じ行を抜き出すといった感じになります。

Comment: 作りたいプログラムに対して、「何が分からない・何に困っているか」をもう少し具体的に説明してみてください。今の内容だと極端な話、Python の基礎的な書き方が分かっているかも (第三者からは) 判断できないため、どこから回答すればいいのかが分かりません。

Answer (score 1):

ふたつのデータを inner join すれば良いです。以下は Pandas の [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) を使った例です。

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([
...   ["aaa00", 123.22, 42.11],
...   ["aba00", 163.22, 73.11],
...   ["acc01", 298.11, 63.28]
... ])
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([
...   ["bbb00", 1872],
...   ["aaa00", 2001],
...   ["aba00", 789],
...   ["caa01", 983]
... ])
>>> df1.merge(df2, how="inner", on=0)
       0     1_x      2   1_y
0  aaa00  123.22  42.11  2001
1  aba00  163.22  73.11   789
```

DataFrame を得るために CSV ファイルから読み込むには、[`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) を使うと良いです。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます！これで試したいと思います！txtファイルを読み込む時は、pd.DataFrameにtxtファイルを書き込めば良いですか、、？

Comment: @ttt 質問文に追記しました。

Answer (score 0):

素の Pythonで。
CSVと思しき形式が簡易ならこんなふうにも可能
(一般的な CSVなら, CSVモジュール使うほうがよいです)
また colabで確認したため, 記述が現在一般的な Pythonより少し古めにしてます

```py
import io

f01 = '''
aaa00,123.22,42.11
aba00,163.22,73.11
acc01,298.11,63.28
'''
f02 = '''
bbb00,1872
aaa00,2001
aba00,789
caa01,983
'''

with io.StringIO(f01.strip()) as fp1:   # with open(fname1) as fp1:
    dct = {ln.split(',')[0]: ln.strip() for ln in fp1}
with io.StringIO(f02.strip()) as fp2:   # with open(fname2) as fp2:
    lst= [','.join([dct[k]]+ v) for ln in fp2
                        for k,*v in (ln.strip().split(','),)if k in dct]

lst
# ['aaa00,123.22,42.11,2001', 'aba00,163.22,73.11,789']
```

Answer (score 0):

あまり明確ではなくてすみません。考えた手順だけ一応書いておきます。
参考にならないかもしれませんのであまり気にしないでください。
1,テキストデータを読み込むor手書きで変数に格納する
2,一列ごとにfor文でリストに格納する(テキスト1はリストa、テキスト2はリストbに格納)
3,aとbから数字だけ別の変数に格納し削除する(数字の入っている変数をaの数字はc、bの数字はdと呼ぶ)
4,aの一つ目の要素=bのn番目の要素のfor文でnをbのリストの要素回bのリストの要素回1加算する。(つまり、aの1行目をbのすべての行と比較する)
5,3をaの要素回繰り返す
これで少し重いですがaのすべての行を1行ずつbのすべての行と比較することができるはずです。
少しでも参考になれば幸いです。